# Maps of different function pointers signatures holded in one map

Tags: c++, unions, stdmap

I want to hold function pointers of different signatures in separate maps. Then I want to hold all this maps in a single map. My current approach:

```
union sig_u {
    func_signature1 fs1;
    func_signature2 fs2;
};

std::map<std::string, sig_u> fs1_insts = {
    {"default_function", sig_u{.fs1=&PointerToDefault}},
    {"dummy_overloaded", sig_u{.fs1=&PointerToDummyOverloaded}}
};

std::map<std::string, sig_u> fs2_insts = {
    {"important_function", sig_u{.fs2=&PointerToImportant}},
    {"dummy_overloaded", sig_u{.fs2=&PointerToDummyOverloaded}}
};

std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, sig_u> > signature = {
   {"group1", fs1_insts},
   {"group2", fs2_insts}
};
```

Then i would like to call this functions in given way:

```
signature["group1"]["dummy_overloaded"](...);
```

Is there a better way to get this behavior ? I am pretty new to C++ programming. I thought about some templates, but couldn't find any solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `std::variant` could be of use here

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::variant`, and read it. Although this is passable for plain function pointers, C++ type-safety is completely bypassed by this kind of an implementation, and you better know exactly which function pointer is which, else [demons will fly out of everyone's noses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).

Comment: containers hold elements of exactly one type. If you want it to hold elements of different types you need "something extra" (eg `std::variant`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will read about std::variant and adjust my design.

Comment: I think you should explain WHY you want to hold function pointers in maps, especially as you are new to C++. It seems as though there might be a completely different design that is better suited for this, as this looks like http://xyproblem.info/